# Cannot use .style notation in JavaScript with VSCode

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code

I am learning HTML/CSS at the moment and somehow hurled to dynamic CSS styling using JavaScript (and wanted to see how deep the rabbit hole goes) and come to the realization that VSCode does not give the option to use {object}.style notation to reach CSSStyleDeclarations. After much exploration, I still achieved what I want by using 'setAttribute('style', 'display:....').

Then I checked both Atom and Notepad++ to see how they handle the problem and surprised that these products support {object}.style notation out of the box.
Can you tell me what I am missing and how can I use this notation with VSCode.

List of extensions I am using:
Beautify by HookyQR
C# by Microsoft
Debugger for Chrome by Microsoft
ESLint by Dirk Baeumer
JavaScript ES6 code snippets by charalampos karypidis
Live Server by Ritwick Dey
npm Intellisense by Christian Kohler
Visual Studio IntelliCode by Microsoft

EDIT. Code (Sorry, haven't included before as it is a very basic thing)

```
let slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');  
slide[0].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: And where is the question itself?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Question a quite unclear, what do you mean by "does not give the option" ? It is an autocomplete issue ?

Comment: Can you show a practical example of `{object}.style` notation?

Comment: Sorry, edited the comment with code. First time posting :-(

Comment: @Apolo, intellisense does not show .style option after selecting the variable, however when you console.log the variable, you can see all CSSStyleDeclarations are already in there under the variable.

Comment: I would prefer to post this question on VSCode forums but "Ask a question" link in VSCode directs to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm using pretty similar code all the time, what is the issue you're facing with it, "_does not give an option to use_" doesn't tell me anything. Do you mean Intellisense doesn't make any suggestions when you're writing that expression?

Comment: @Teemu, thanks, that is correct, there is no intellisense option for style after choosing slide[0].

Comment: I think that's because the value of `slide[0]` is only available at the runtime, Intellisense can't give any hints for runtime values.